# Test multiple projects on the same device, at the same time.

Tags: xcode

I apologise in advance as I've only been working in Xcode for a few weeks... Is there a way to test multiple projects on the same device, more importantly, at the same time. Every time I test a new project on the device, the previous project is removed/replaced. I'm sure there's an easy solution, I just can't find it.